# Updating component in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am building a site what lets you build a time table (for school subjects) I wrote a component that fetches data from database and then calculates corect placement in time table

```
       <div class="timetable col-lg-8">
            <div class="rowT">
                <div style="width : 16%">Day</div>
                <div *ngFor="let head of timeTableHeader" 
                     [style.width]="headerWidth">
                    {{head}}

                </div>
            </div>

            <div *ngFor="let sublists of allData" class="rowT">
                <div *ngFor="let sublist of sublists"
                id="{{sublist[0]}}"
                class="timetable-cell" 
                [style]="getMyStyles(sublist[1])"
                (click)="showDetails($event,sublist[3])">

                {{sublist[0]}}


            </div>
        </div>
```

now I wrote a form which allows somebody to edit particular subject(e.g. time changed or class room) it works fine it saves the changes in DB adn now I want to show these changes in my view I thought I just call the function that calculates subject placements in time table but that results in rendering the time table again and leaving the old one there.

```
@Component({

  selector: 'time-table',
  templateUrl: './timetable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timetable.component.css']
})

export class TimeTableComponent {

  allSubjects: Array<Subject>; 
  headerWidth: string;
  timeTableHeader: Array<string> = new Array();
  allData: Array<Array<Array<string>>> = new Array<Array<Array<string>>>();


  constructor(private http: Http) {        
   this.fetchAndMake(); //function that fetches data and calls other function 
                        //to make calculations... too long and not sure if relevant 
                       // so I wont post it here        
  }

  fetchAndMake(){
    this.allSubjects = new Array<Subject>();
     let params : URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('userName', this.authService.currentUser.userName);

    let reqOption = new RequestOptions();
    reqOption.params = params;

    this.http.get(this.configurations.baseUrl + "/SubjectModel/TimeTable", reqOption).subscribe(result => {
        this.makeSubjects(result.json());

    });
}
  updateSubject(subj){
    let subject = subj as SubjectData;       

    this.http.post(this.configurations.baseUrl + "/SubjectModel/UpdateSubject",helper)
        .subscribe();

    this.editSubjectView = false;

    this.fetchAndMake();

}

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Hard to comment without seeing your http calls. It would be good to move "allData: Array<Array<Array<string>>> = new Array<Array<Array<string>>>();" , making it as the first line in fetchAndMake(). That way you can be sure if the timetable is empty , the function is called and there was some issue with the http call

Comment: I moved the initialization of allData Array to makeSubject() so it would create a new Srray when I am fetching the data (I hoped that would resolve the issue with rendering it again) and I posted more code hope it helps you to understand what I am trying to do :)

Comment: Can you move the this.fetchAndMake() inside updateSUbject to the Subscribe of the post, inside this.http.post(this.configurations.baseUrl + "/SubjectModel/UpdateSubject",helper)
        .subscribe();

Comment: I dont understand what you want to say, I am calling this.fetchAndMake() inside updateSubject() because I want to fetch the updated data and re-calculate the subject parameter(day,time placement) but as i said above it leaves the old time table in place and renders a new one

Comment: I mean there is chance that second fetch and make gets called before the post is complete, so if you give like
this.http.post(this.configurations.baseUrl + "/SubjectModel/UpdateSubject",helper)
        .subscribe( result =>{this.fetchAndMake();});

you can make sure it won't happen

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that

> this.fetchAndMake()

gets called before

> this.http.post(this.configurations.baseUrl +
>   "/SubjectModel/UpdateSubject",helper)
>           .subscribe();

is complete in updateSubject function.  Subscribe just initiates the call , if you want to ensure that the new data is updated only after the post is complete, edit the updateSubject() function as follows :-

```
updateSubject(subj){
    let subject = subj as SubjectData;       

    this.http.post(this.configurations.baseUrl + "/SubjectModel/UpdateSubject",helper)
        .subscribe(result =>{
this.allData = new Array<Array<Array<string>>>();

this.fetchAndMake();
});

    this.editSubjectView = false;



}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion but it doesnt solve my issue, it leaves the old one there and after that it renders the  updated one.

Comment: sorry couldn't help, I have added all data initiialization also into the subscribe. It shoudln't make a difference if you already have moved intitialization to fetchandMake

Answer (score 0):

First you should not be fetching the data directly from the component but rather from a data service. When you use a data service and inject it into components that use it the data service is a singleton.  Not sure if that solves your problem but in any case it is a design issue you should look into before you go any further down this road.

Also, you are calling the primary function in the constructor.  The only thing you should be doing in the constructor is to inject the data service.  You need to implement the OnInit interface and call your function that fetches the data from the data service you injected in the constructor in the ngOnInit() method.

Check out some of the many Angular 4 tutorials and look for examples of creating a data service, making it a provider in app.module.ts.  Then in your component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyDataService } from '../shared/my-data.service';
....
export class TimeTableComponent Implements OnInit {
...

constructor(private _mydata: MyDataService)  { }

ngOnInit(){ 
// call method in data service that fetches data and do whatever you need to
// with the returned result.  Now everything will be available to your view
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips I will look into it but it could be a few days before I get to it, I will let you know then if that helped me with my problem